# Set PHP version in Netbeans 7 for non-project files

Tags: php, netbeans, php-5.3, netbeans-plugins, lambda

I'm editing a PHP file in Netbeans that is not part of a project. Although I have PHP 5.3 installed, Netbeans complains about my use of a lambda function: "Language feature not compatible with PHP version indicated in project settings".

Is there a way to tell Netbeans to think in 5.3 when I don't have project settings to edit?

I'm using Netbeans 7.0 with PHP 5.3.3 on Ubuntu.

UPDATE: The code is working, it's just the inspection that is borken.

Comment: @Neal next time you have a bug in your code, just ignore it, this will be easier than fix it

Comment: @Neal I'll probably disable the inspection until I find a solution. Still, not ideal when your IDE is telling you stuff is broken that isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently did an update to my NetBeans (v7.0.1). I just tried creating a lambda fn and the IDE didn't show any warnings/errors. Try updating your NB.

Answer (score 16):

Right click your project in the Projects tab, click Properties, then on the Sources tab, set the PHP Version. I'm using Netbeans 7.1.2

Comment: Is this something you can do when you are not working with a project? Intuitively I imagine not but I do not work with Netbeans anymore and not going to install just to check this.

Answer (score 4):

Go to File Menu of net beans and select project properties of the project and change the version of php from # PHP Version : PHP 5.6 or another.
This Error Showing for PHP version(**language feature not compatible with php version indicated in project settings**)

[image: This Error Showing for PHP version(language feature not compatible with php version indicated in project settings)]
[image]

[image]

[image]